# Export specific data from PDF to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, pdf

I have used this code to extract specific data from PDF, how can I store it as a XML file.

```
private string ParseCodeText(string sourceStr)
{
string pattern = @"\(\d{3}\)\s\d\s\d{8}\s\d{10}\s\d";
string extractedCode = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(sourceStr, pattern).Value;
return extractedCode;
}
```

XML file format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Files_table>


-<Files>

<File_name>Filename1</File_name>

<Page>1</Page>

<code>(00) 123 456</code>

<Printed>Y</Printed>

</Files>


-<Files>

<File_name>Filename1</File_name>

<Page>2</Page>

<code>(00) 456 789</code>

<Printed>N</Printed>

</Files>

</Files_table>
```

Comment: how do you want your resulting xml to look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Files_table>


-<Files>

<File_name>Filename1</File_name>

<Page>1</Page>

<code>(00) 123 456</code>

<Printed>Y</Printed>

</Files>


-<Files>

<File_name>Filename1</File_name>

<Page>2</Page>

<code>(00) 456 789</code>

<Printed>N</Printed>

</Files>

</Files_table>

Comment: Actually I didn't get the extract data part. This questions seems irrelevant to PDF and is about XML.

Answer (score 0):

Well the abstract answer is: create your data objects (something like this):

```
    public class  FilterTable
    {
        public MyFile[] Files { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyFile
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Printed { get; set; }
    }
```

Fill them with your data

And use the [XMLSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize the data.

You will have to set some attributes to get the naming correct.